# What does "seamless power transfer" mean?

Tags: power, power-electronics

In power electronics context, is there any technical definition of "seamless power transfer"?. Does it mean a smooth power transfer without a transient variations regardless the disturbances in the input, or it has some other meanings?

Comment: It could mean one of a number of things depending on context. Can you provide any?

Comment: I have read this term many times in multiple research papers, and I feel it is very vague/loose term to be used in a research papers. So I thought if there a technical definition or standard of such term.

Here I quote a paragraph from one of these papers 
 http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6388591

"On unavailability of AC grid on any one side, the scheme
takes care of the other side connected critical loads and
seamlessly transfers the real power through the DC bus"

Comment: These are also called, in some contexts, "Automatic Buss Transfer (ABT)" or "bumpless" transfer. I've made ABT switches for marine applications, some are as simple as relays (although not really "bumpless", but the power supplies typically have enough capacitance to soften the transfer), or much more complicated mechanisms.

Comment: not much more than "power transfer", at least not without context.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that it depends on context. In the example you provided, it seems to suggest that as soon as a critical load is not receiving power, a backup DC source begins providing power. Seamless in this case would be that there isn't a significant amount of time that the load is unpowered.

I think your answer could also be found in the abstract, as follows:

> The presented results show that seamless power is
>   provided to the critical loads connected to the grid with
>   loss/failure of generation, without any transients in voltage.

Answer (score 0):

This is of importance to customers who need uninterrupted sources of power in plants, grids or customer service with redundant sources and automatic transfer switching.